# How to get the First frame from Video file?

Tags: android

I have some video files.I need to show every video file as a ImageView .On that Image view i need to set first frame of the video as a image.How to do this?

Comment: You can do it with Glide as well. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487567/392506)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check wordpress App they are taking thumbnail from Video

[Here](https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser) is the link for source code of Wordpress App

Thank you.