# create video thumbnail from video path

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I have an HTTP path that contains video files. I want to show a thumbnail of that video. I had a look online, but could not find what I need.

Comment: Is it a YouTube video?

Comment: no..its not a youtube video

Comment: Try this, using a `VideoView`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079593/how-to-set-the-preview-image-in-videoview-before-playing

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/32689023/2769892

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Generate a thumbnail from a video url in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android)